# Store xml string in xml file

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to store XML string in XML file in the following way

```
String appData =  "<Data><element><displayname>John</displayname></element></Data>";


org.w3c.dom.Element appData= doc.createElement("appData");
rootElement.appendChild(appData);
org.w3c.dom.Element appXmlData= doc.createElement("myData");
appData.appendChild(appXmlData);
appXmlData.setTextContent(appData);

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(path1));
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

the data is stored in the xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<appData>
<myData>
      &lt;Data&gt;&lt;element&gt;&lt;displayname&gt;John&lt;/displayname&gt;&lt;/element&gt;&lt;/Data&gt;
</myData>
```

What i want is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<appData>
<myData>
    <Data><element><displayname>John</displayname></element></Data>
</myData>
```

Help me in achieving this

Comment: You can't as "<" ">" are special keywords for XML, they can't appear in it's content. Instead they are replaced with &lt; and &gt; respectively. Any xml containing "<" ">" as values in any content will not be a proper XML and will fail validation

Comment: read more here: http://xml.silmaril.ie/specials.html

Comment: You can use `CDATA` & add your String inside `myData` in that then only it will retains `<` & `>` symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Like you did a

```
org.w3c.dom.Element appXmlData= doc.createElement("myData");
```

you have to create child elements for your other nodes:

```
org.w3c.dom.Element dataNode= doc.createElement("Data");
appXmlData.appendChild(dataNode);
```

and so on...Since you are using the dom api, it will escape the xml content in your node.

Comment: Yes I can do this way.but the thing is i have a large xml string which is making me to look for an alternative